# How do I set up virtualenv as a PyDev Interpreter?

Tags: virtualenv, pydev

I am following steps in this post to set up my PyDev IDE.

https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2011/08/31/getting-started-using-python-eclipse/

I am unable to setup the virtualenv as an Interpreter.

My OS is Windows 10

PYTHON_HOME is pointing to 3.6.

I installed virtualenv like this and verified it is successful:

> pip install virtualenv
>   virtualenv --version 
>   15.1.0

Now, I try to setup an interpreter in PyDev IDE at Windows>Preferences>PyDev>Interpreters>Python Interpreter

I point to the virtualenv.exe here:

C:\%PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts\virtualenv.exe

## PyDEV IDE gives me this error:

Unable to get info on interpreter: C:\%PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts\virtualenv.exe
Common reasons include:

- Unsupported version
- Specifying an invalid interpreter

Answer (score 0):

You should not set the virtualenv.exe as the interpreter, but the python executable created under the virtual environment.

i.e.: it'd be python.exe on windows in that virtualenv or just python on Linux.